# While loop showing no information

Tags: javascript

i am trying to write this code but nothing is shown.

```
    var a =10;
while(a <= 0){

    document.write(a);
    a=a+1;
 }
```

Why is that?

Comment: `a` is never less than or equal to zero.

Comment: I feel your condition would be `while(a <= 10)` it's 10 and not 0 and probably you are wondering why didn it enter the loop even once or you got to do a `a=a-1;` or `a--` instead of `a=a+1;`

Comment: To expand on @NightShadeQueen's comment, the loop never runs. The condition is false to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a is never less than or equal to zero..your code should be like this:

```
var a =10;
while(a >= 0){

    document.write(a);
    a=a-1;
 }
```